# Show JvmHeapSize from Talend ESB to Prometheus

Tags: jmx, talend, grafana, apache-karaf, jmx-exporter

I want to get the jvm metrics from Talend ESB and to show the metrics to Grafana.

I can easily see them with JConsole but i do not know how to expose them to Grafana.

My idea was to get the metrics with JMX Exporter and to expose them to prometheus and then to show them on Grafana but when I tried the JMX Exporter,I faced a  problem to start it.

> C:\Users\admin\Desktop\jmx_exporter-master>java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=9090:talend-config.yml
>   Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : ./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar

Some idea or example how to get the JVM heap size from Talend ESB and to expose them to Prometheus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone this project: https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter then navigate to jmx_prometheus_httpserver folder, change the version in pom.xml to 0.12.0 and then execute **mvn clean install**
After that you can find jmx_prometheus_httpserver-0.12.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar in the target folder.

Create talend-config.yml file and add this lines to it:

```
---
startDelaySeconds: 0
#hostPort: 
username: tadmin
password: tadmin 
jmxUrl: service:jmx:rmi://localhost:44444/jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/karaf-trun
ssl: false
lowercaseOutputName: false
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: false
```

Save it and execute this command:

**java -jar jmx_prometheus_httpserver-0.12.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar localhost:9595 talend-config.yml**

If you want you can change the ip and the port.
After executing the command you can access the metrics on this link:

http://localhost:9595/metrics

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't make much sense. The question is about using the java agent, and the answer is about instead running an httpserver. The main README page explains the difference between the two. https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter

I ran into the same issue. The issue has nothing to do with prometheus jmx exporter itself. The problem can occur when the agent cannot be found by Java. Ensure that the jar file exists at the path you are using. Maybe look at the permissions of the file. Try quoting the argument, like

```
-javaagent:"<path to jmx agent jar and other arguments>"
```